# Caching redirects in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, redirect, pagespeed

Recently i was testing site performance on PageSpeed, where i came to know that we have Landing page issues, here's what PageSpeed told us:

```
To speed up page load times for visitors of your site, remove as many landing page redirections as possible, and make any required redirections cacheable if possible.
```

It further says:

```
http://www.avnetwork.com/ is a non-cacheable redirect to http://www.avnetwork.com/index
```

Can anyone tell me how to cache the redirects in asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programatically you can try something like this:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
Response.AddHeader("Vary", "User-Agent, Accept-Encoding");
Response.Redirect("http://www.avnetwork.com/index");
```